# Why won't my grunt proxy work? - Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have been working on setting up a proxy with Grunt.  I am able to connect to my Grunt server, but when I try to hit the proxy I get a 404.  Here is my `Gruntfile.js`

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect:{
      development: {
        port: 9000,
        base: 'app',
        keepalive: true,
        livereload: {
          options: {
            middleware: function() {
              return proxySnippet;
            }
          }
        },
        proxies: [{
          context: '/name',
          host: 'http://99.42.222.76:3000/users.json',
          changeOrigin: true
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', ['configureProxies', 'connect']);
};
```

I have tried to use [this](http://www.fettblog.eu/blog/2013/09/20/using-grunt-connect-proxy/) blog to help me set up everything, but I still am not having any luck.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not programming related - looks like a networking/configuration issue

Comment: What makes you say that? Do you have a `Gruntfile.js` that has a proxy set up and works?  If so could you give me an example?

Comment: This is not a programming question - please read the FAQ.

Comment: @KevinDTimm This absolutely IS a programming question - please reread and look up the tagged technologies if you don't know them.

Comment: @jhamm Could you share your package.json file so we know what grunt plugins you are using?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the issue is that you don't want to use the full URL in the host: of the proxy configuration. According to the docs (https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy), the host should not include the `http`.

Quote:

> options.host
>
> Type: String
>
> The host to proxy to. Should not start with the http/https protocol.

I think the proxies section you want should look like the below. The host indicates the IP address or host name to proxy to, the port indicates the port to proxy to, and the rewrite indicates a translation from /name to /users.json.

```
    proxies: [{
      context: '/name',
      host: '99.42.222.76',
      port: 3000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      rewrite: { '^/name': '/users.json' }
    }]
```